# It's possible to add an interface to a Docker container for speed up connectivity?

Tags: docker, docker-network

I am having this issue for a while I am *not sure* how to fix it. I have a Docker container running PHP+Apache with an application. The MySQL and MongoDB servers are on the same network as the host. So:

- **MySQL DB Server IP:** 192.168.1.98
- **Mongo DB Server IP:** 192.168.1.98
- **Host:** 192.168.1.90

For some reason the connectivity between the application running on the container and the DB server is pretty slow and sometimes it takes more than one minute running long queries.

I can say the problem is not the DB server because running the same application on the same server works fast so I think is something related to networking but I am not sure what or why.

Can any give me some advice around this?

Answer (score 0):

You have not given much information, but based on what you have described

1. The simplest reason could be that the amount of data that is being transferred across the network is high. Even though the hosts are on the same network, the time taken to transfer a large file across a pair of machines on the network would be considerably slower than copying it from the same host.
2. Since it seems like you are running both MongoDB and MySQL DB on the same host, they could be easily interfering with the execution of each other. While the container provides isolation among them at the operating system level, the hardware does not identify containers. When both containers try to use the disk, the performance can degrade.

I have personally run into both these issues at different times and while they seem simple they can have significant impact on the performance. It would be nice if you could provide some additional information to help better understand your problem.

Comment: *additional* information such as .... ? What do you need? I am experimenting a slight improve on times, don't know why or how but I can see everything working faster

Comment: As the first step, try moving mongo db and mysql to different machines. Try to give concrete numbers about how much time the query takes to execute on different machines. 
After that try running wireshark on the client container. ( look at https://medium.com/@chughtapan/running-wireshark-on-docker-ac90ebc4907b#.yu18xfpq4 ) change the container ID to your client container and execute this code on the host. Run the query and then measure how much traffic is being transferred between the client and the databases. Once we have these numbers, we can get a better understanding of how to improve